# how to use cv::VideoCapture::waitAny() in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to find a way to asynchronously check to see if the next frame of the camera that I get using videocapture is ready.

I came across waitAny() which is described to "Wait for ready frames from VideoCapture.".

in the OpenCV documentation, I didn't find any useful info on how to use this or what are the use cases.

I've been searching the net for two days now and the only thing I found is how to define the parameters this function needs(I'm new to c++) and I don't know how to fill them and what are their use cases.
here is the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ade1c7b8d276fea4d000bc0af0f1017b3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach that IMO is fairly common is to have a pair of threads -- one that "produces" frames from `VideoCapture` (calls [VideoCapture::read()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1) in a loop), and another that actually uses these frames (a "consumer"). The producer pushes images onto a queue (that's shared across two threads), while the consumer pops them.
In this situation, checking whether a camera has produced an image amounts to checking whether the queue is empty.

By itself, `VideoCapture` does not provide such an async API.

That said, if you want to use `waitAny`, and if you have a single camera, you could do something like this:

```
VideoCapture cap = /* get the VideoCapture object from somewhere */


constexpr int64 kTimeoutNs = 1000;
std::vector<int> ready_index;
cv::Mat image;
if (VideoCapture::waitAny({cap}, ready_index, kTimeoutNs)) {
  // Camera was ready; get image.
  cap.retrieve(image);
} else {
  // Camera was not ready; do something else. 
}
```

Above, `VideoCapture::waitAny` will wait for the specified timeout (1 microsecond) for the camera to produce a frame, and will return after this period.
If the camera is ready, it will return true (and will also populate `ready_index` with the index of the ready camera. Since you only have a single camera, the vector will be either empty or non-empty).

That said, `waitAny` seems to only be supported by `VideoCapture` sources that use V4L in the backend.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. a couple of questions: how can I determine if a camera uses V4L? what happens if I don't give waitAny the timeout parameter?

Comment: If a timeout is not provided (or equivalently, if it's set to 0), then the function blocks indefinitely until the frame is available. In a single-camera case, it is then similar to  [VideoCapture::grab()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#bool%20VideoCapture::grab()).